# Check which boxes does a vector cross in a grid

Tags: java, math, vector, 2d

I'm working on a simple visibility algorithm, I want to check if some point can be seen by some other point (there are obstacles).

So let's say I have a 2d array [][] and 2 points: Point A ([A1][A2]) and point B ([B1][B2]).

I create a vector between the center of those two points V=(A,B) and now I need to check which boxes of the grid are crossed by the vector V.

If some of those boxes are indeed an obstacle then I can say that point B can't be seen from point A.

[Detailed graphic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzb9U.jpg)

Is there a way to check which positions of the 2d array are crossed by the (imaginary) drawn vector?